# how to change multiple options of webpage using mechanize and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I have to scrape all options available in [here](http://ceojk.nic.in/ElectionPDF/Main.aspx). Using mechanize I have select first two controls (report type and language). Now there are three drop down list. second is dependent on first and thir is dependent on second. How I can solve it. My starting code for first two fields is give below

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
br = mechanize.Browser()

url="http://ceojk.nic.in/ElectionPDF/Main.aspx"
response = br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="Form1")
control_1 = br.form.find_control("RadioButtonList1")
control_2 = br.form.find_control("RadioButtonList2")
submit = br.form.find_control("Button1")

br[control_1.name]=["PS Wise Report"]
br[control_2.name]=["English"]
response = br.submit()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
for item in soup.find_all('option'):
    print item['value']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was quite exciting to debug (you cannot imagine how many things I've tried and learned while trying to solve it).

Here is the working code that mimics the behavior in the browser step-by-step selecting the first District, AC and PS (just passing `["1"]` values - you might need to improve that - for instance, read the options and add a option name -> value map):

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()

url = "http://ceojk.nic.in/ElectionPDF/Main.aspx"
response = br.open(url)

br.select_form(name="Form1")
br["RadioButtonList1"] = ["PS Wise Report"]
br["RadioButtonList2"] = ["English"]
br.submit()

# getting ACs
br.select_form(name="Form1")
br["DistlistP"] = ["1"]
br.submit(name="BtnPs")

# getting PSes
br.select_form(name="Form1")
br["AclistP"] = ["1"]
br.submit(name="BtnPs")

# getting report
br.select_form(name="Form1")
br["PslistP"] = ["1"]
response = br.submit(name="BtnPs")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print(soup.find(id="Pnlfile"))
```

At the end it prints the HTML code of the "File" block appearing on the right in the browser.